# How can I prove certain properties of these vector fields on $S^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

On the unit 3-sphere in 4-dimensional Cartesian coordinate space, one can find a set of three orthonormal vector fields that parallelize the 3-sphere. (Utilize the correspondence between the unit 3-sphere and the coordinates of a geometric algebra rotor, and then infinitesimal displacements on the 3-sphere map to/from infinitesimal rotations in 3 orthogonal directions. See below for explicit expressions of the vector fields.)

It turns out it is easiest to find the vector fields in terms of the extrinsic 4d coordinates on the 3-sphere - they are just linear functions (and very simple ones at that) of the 4d coordinates. But there are some properties of these vector fields that I want to prove - namely, that they satisfy certain commutation relations (analogous to the commutation relations of the angular momentum operators in quantum mechanics) and that the vector fields are divergence-free - that I only know how to prove by introducing an intrinsic 3d coordinate system. But doing so is laborious.

My question is, is there a simple/elegant way to prove the commutation and divergence properties of these vector fields without introducing an intrinsic coordinate system, e.g. by using their symmetry properties or the fact that they generate infinitesimal rotations in orthogonal directions?

For further info: on the 3-sphere characterized by the set of points $(w,x,y,z)$ such that $w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, the three vector fields are:
$$e_1=(-x,w,z,-y)$$
$$e_2=(-y,-z,w,x)$$
$$e_3=(-z,y,-x,w)$$

And the Lie brackets that I want to prove are:
$$[e_i,e_j]=2\epsilon_{ijk}e_k$$

Comment: This question is difficult to understand and might be too abstract for a good answer. It would help to write the three fields in 4d, and exactly what the "certain commutation relations", or at least one or two of them, are.

Comment: It is not so laborious to think of the 3-sphere as the Lie group of unit quaternions. In that case you can pick the vectors i, j, k at the identity and left translate them everywhere to obtain an orthonormal frame field on all of S^3. By then extending this radially you can do your calculations in Euclidean 4-space if you like.

Comment: @aschepler thanks, I ran out of time to put that information in when I originally posted the question; got a second to come back to it so I have added it in!

Comment: @Dan Asimov are you saying that treating these vector fields as being in flat 4d space rather than the 3-sphere would give the same answers? How could I show that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$ correspond to multiplications of unit quaternions by ${\rm i}$, ${\rm j}$ and ${\rm k}$. This means that one can compute their flows with exponentials. For instance:

$$\Phi_{e_1}(t, (w,x,y,z)) = {\rm e}^{{\rm i}t}(w+{\rm i}x+{\rm j}y+{\rm k}z)$$reads only $$\Phi_{e_1}(t,(w,x,y,z)) = (w\cos t-x\sin t, x\cos t+w\sin t, y\cos t-z\sin t, z\cos t+y\sin t).$$Clearly $\Phi_{e_1}(t,(w,x,y,z)) \in S^3$ whenever $(w,x,y,z) \in S^3$. In fact, $\Phi_{e_1}(t,\cdot)\colon S^3 \to S^3$ is an orientation-preserving isometry, which in particular preserves the volume form. This means that $\mathcal{L}_{e_1}{\rm vol} = 0$. But in general, $\mathcal{L}_X{\rm vol} = ({\rm div}(X)){\rm vol}$, so we conclude that ${\rm div}(e_1)= 0$. Now, the three quaternionic imaginary units are in equal standing, so we also conclude that ${\rm div}(e_2) = {\rm div}(e_3) = 0$.

As for the Lie bracket, let me elaborate on why there is no problem in regarding them as fields in $\Bbb R^4$. We have fields $E_1$, $E_2$ and $E_3$ in $\Bbb R^4$, given by the same formulas as $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$, so that $E_1|_{S^3} = e_1$, $E_2|_{S^3} = e_2$ and $E_3|_{S^3} = e_3$. This implies that $[E_i,E_j]|_{S^3} = [e_i,e_j]$, where the former Lie bracket is computed in $\Bbb R^4$ and the latter in $S^3$. Now, $E_1$, $E_2$ and $E_3$ correspond to multiplications of arbitrary quaternions by ${\rm i}$, ${\rm j}$ and ${\rm k}$, and the Lie bracket in $\Bbb R^4$ corresponds to the commutator of such $\Bbb R$-linear maps. So, for example, we have that $$[E_1,E_2] \cong {\rm ij} - {\rm ji} = 2{\rm k} \cong 2E_3.$$Similarly for the other relations.

Comment: Another comment about the first part of my answer: I have in fact proved that the three fields are Killing fields (and every Killing field is divergence-free). And if I recall right, one can only get (local) frames consisting of Killing fields if the manifold has constant sectional curvature, so that's a bonus.