# Another property of vector fields on $S^3$

Tags: differential-geometry

On the 3-sphere $S^3$ characterized by the set of points $(w,x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, one can define six different vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^4$ terms as follows:

$$e_1=(-x,w,z,-y)$$
$$e_2=(-y,-z,w,x)$$
$$e_3=(-z,y,-x,w)$$
And:
$$e_1'=(-x,w,-z,y)$$
$$e_2'=(-y,z,w,-x)$$
$$e_3'=(-z,-y,x,w)$$
(These arise from left and right multiplication of a geometric algebra rotor by the basis bivectors, or the equivalent operation on unit quaternions.) Considered as vector fields in $S^3$, each of the frames $e_i$ and $e_i'$ form an orthonormal basis to the tangent space; each of the six vector fields is divergence-free, and they have the following Lie brackets:
$$[e_i,e_j]=2\epsilon_{ijk}e_k$$
$$[e_i',e_j']=-2\epsilon_{ijk}e_k'$$
$$[e_i,e_j']=0$$

I am trying to find a way to prove that, when considered as derivative operators on scalar fields on $S^3$, they obey:
$$e_ie_i = e_i'e_i'$$

But short of direct calculation in some coordinate basis I haven't been able to come up with anything. Is there a simple way to prove this property?

Edit: for clarification, here I'm using implicit summation over repeated Latin indices even though they are all subscripts (since upper/lower index distinction can be ignored for orthonormal frames).

(This is somewhat related to my earlier question [How can I prove certain properties of these vector fields on $S^3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244684/how-can-i-prove-certain-properties-of-these-vector-fields-on-s3))

Answer (score 1):

I finally hit upon an answer shortly after posting the question, so here it is.

Write $e_i = e_i^\mu\partial_\mu$ and $e_i' = e_i'^\mu\partial_\mu$ in any coordinate system. Now we can calculate:

$$e_ie_i=e_i^\mu \partial_\mu (e_i^\nu \partial_\nu) =e_i^\mu \partial_\mu (e_i^\nu )\partial_\nu +e_i^\mu e_i^\nu \partial_\mu \partial_\nu $$
And similarly:
$$e_i'e_i'=e_i'^\mu \partial_\mu (e_i'^\nu \partial_\nu) =e_i'^\mu \partial_\mu (e_i'^\nu )\partial_\nu +e_i'^\mu e_i'^\nu \partial_\mu \partial_\nu $$

Because the vector fields are orthonormal, the inverse metric tensor can be written $g^{-1}=e_i\otimes e_i=e_i'\otimes e_i'$ leading to the relationship:

$$e_i^\mu e_i^\nu = e_i'^\mu e_i'^\nu = g^{\mu\nu}$$
This can be differentiated and then rearranged:
$$\partial_\mu (e_i^\mu) e_i^\nu + e_i^\mu \partial_\mu (e_i^\nu)= \partial_\mu (e_i'^\mu) e_i'^\nu + e_i'^\mu \partial_\mu (e_i'^\nu)$$
$$e_i'^\mu \partial_\mu (e_i'^\nu) -  e_i^\mu \partial_\mu (e_i^\nu) = \partial_\mu (e_i^\mu) e_i^\nu - \partial_\mu (e_i'^\mu) e_i'^\nu$$

Because the vector fields are divergence-free:
$$\nabla\cdot e_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det g}}\partial_\mu (\sqrt{\det g} e_i^\mu) = 0$$
$$\frac{1}{2}g^{\kappa\lambda}\partial_\mu(g_{\lambda\kappa})e_i^\mu + \partial_\mu(e_i^\mu)=0$$
$$\partial_\mu(e_i^\mu)=-\frac{1}{2}g^{\kappa\lambda}\partial_\mu(g_{\lambda\kappa})e_i^\mu$$
And the same goes for $e_i'$. Therefore:
$$e_i'^\mu \partial_\mu (e_i'^\nu) -  e_i^\mu \partial_\mu (e_i^\nu) = -\frac{1}{2}g^{\kappa\lambda}\partial_\mu(g_{\lambda\kappa})e_i^\mu e_i^\nu +\frac{1}{2}g^{\kappa\lambda}\partial_\mu(g_{\lambda\kappa})e_i'^\mu e_i'^\nu=0$$

Now we can take the difference $e_i'e_i' - e_ie_i$:
$$e_i'e_i' - e_ie_i = (e_i'^\mu \partial_\mu (e_i'^\nu) -  e_i^\mu \partial_\mu (e_i^\nu))\partial_\nu + (e_i'^\mu e_i'^\nu - e_i^\mu e_i^\nu)\partial_\mu\partial_\nu$$
Which results in:
$$e_i'e_i' - e_ie_i = 0$$
QED. (Though I'm guessing there is probably a way simpler way to do it.)